# html button stay in disabled status after a form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my below code. there are total 8 textboxes wrapped with divs, ids from `fa1` to `fa8`.

1. fa1 and fa2 are set to display by default
2. using add \ remove buttons(`addfa` and `removefa`) to add and remove other divs and also using a `hidden` input element to track the count using its `value`(default value 3)
3. Add button get disabled once it show all hidden div (that is at `countfa` = 9) and the remove buton get enabled once there is 3 or more textboxes (ie `countfa` value 4 or more )
4. fa3 to fa8 set to `display:none` and using above mentioned add \ remove ids to display them
5. I need to keep the textbox along data which entered by user after form submit.

Issue I am facing:
I am using a php code for hidden input element to update its `value` depednds upon the user's div id selection after form submit. I see that eventhough there are 3 or more textboxes after form submit, the remove button keep in disabled state. I have checked whether the hidden input `value` is updating with the new value and i see it getting updated, but still the remove button will be disabled state.
any idea why it not showing in enabled state.

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<form  id="main" name="main" action="#text" method="post" > 

<div id="fa1">
<input  class="textbox" id="tbox1" name="tbox1" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['tbox1'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['tbox1']); }?>" /></span>
</div>

<div id="fa2">
<input  class="textbox" id="tbox2" name="tbox2" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['tbox2'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['tbox2']); }?>" /></span>
</div>

<div id="fa3" style="<?php if(empty($_POST['tbox3'])) { echo "display:none;"; } else { echo "display:block;"; } ?>">
<input  class="textbox" id="tbox3" name="tbox3" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['tbox3'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['tbox3']); }?>" /></span>
</div>

<div id="fa4" style="<?php if(empty($_POST['tbox4'])) { echo "display:none;"; } else { echo "display:block;"; } ?>">
<input  class="textbox" id="tbox4" name="tbox4" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['tbox4'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['tbox4']); }?>" /></span>
</div>

<div id="fa5" style="<?php if(empty($_POST['tbox5'])) { echo "display:none;"; } else { echo "display:block;"; } ?>">
<input  class="textbox" id="tbox5" name="tbox5" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['tbox5'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['tbox5']); }?>" /></span>
</div>

<div id="fa6" style="<?php if(empty($_POST['tbox6'])) { echo "display:none;"; } else { echo "display:block;"; } ?>">
<input  class="textbox" id="tbox6" name="tbox6" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['tbox6'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['tbox6']); }?>" /></span>
</div>

<div id="fa7" style="<?php if(empty($_POST['tbox7'])) { echo "display:none;"; } else { echo "display:block;"; } ?>">
<input  class="textbox" id="tbox7" name="tbox7" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['tbox7'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['tbox7']); }?>" /></span>
</div>

<div id="fa8" style="<?php if(empty($_POST['tbox8'])) { echo "display:none;"; } else { echo "display:block;"; } ?>">
<input  class="textbox" id="tbox8" name="tbox8" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['tbox8'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['tbox8']); }?>" /></span>
</div>

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['countfa'])){  
 $valueid = $_POST['countfa'];
 ?>
<input  type="hidden" id="countfa" name="countfa" value="<?= $valueid ?>" readonly>
<?php
 }else{
  ?>

<input  type="hidden" id="countfa" name="countfa" value="3" readonly> 
 <?php
 }
?> 
<button type="button" onClick="AddNewFa();" id="addfa" > + Add New FA </button>
<button  type="button" onClick="RemoveNewFa();" id="removefa" disabled="disabled"> - Remove FA</button> 

<input  id="generate" type="submit"  name="script" value="create my symcli script" />

</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

and my javascript code:

```
function AddNewFa() 
{
var facount = parseInt($('#countfa').val(),9) ;
document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = facount;
    if( facount < 10)
{
        facount = facount+1;
        document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = facount;
            for(i=3;i<10;i++)
                {
                    if( i<facount )
                        $('#fa'+i).slideDown("fast");
                    else
                        $('#fa'+i).slideUp("fast"); 
                }
    $('#countfa').val(facount);  
}
    if( facount >=9 )
    { $('#addfa').attr('disabled','disabled');} 
    if( facount >=4 )
    { $('#removefa').removeAttr("disabled");}
} 


function RemoveNewFa() 
{
var facount = parseInt($('#countfa').val(),10) ;
document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML = facount;
    if( facount >3)
{
        facount = facount-1;
        document.getElementById("test4").innerHTML = facount;
            for(i=3;i<10;i++)
                {
                    if( i<facount )
                        $('#fa'+i).slideDown("fast");
                    else
                        $('#fa'+i).slideUp("fast");                 
                }
                $('#countfa').val(facount); 
            }        
        if( facount <=3 )
            { $('#removefa').attr('disabled','disabled');} 
        if( facount <=8 )
            { $('#addfa').removeAttr("disabled");       }   
    }
```

I have setup a [**PHP FIDDLE**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/d2g-euj) for this
Note: In php fiddle the add button not functioning after form submit. But I see on actual site it working fine. remove button still not working

Comment: you say they remain disabled after a form submit - are you not missing a PHP condition in the following HTML part to actually remove the "disabled" part when the page is being displayed? `<button  type="button" onClick="RemoveNewFa();" id="removefa" disabled="disabled"> - Remove FA</button> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason your buttons are displaying as they are is because the code you have to enable/disable them is placed within the `click` handlers of each of the items.

You should move the following code :

```
if( facount >=9 )
{ $('#addfa').attr('disabled','disabled');} 
if( facount >=4 )
{ $('#removefa').removeAttr("disabled");}
```

Into a seperate function, i.e.

```
function CheckButtons() {
    var facount = parseInt($('#countfa').val(),9) ;
    if( facount >=9 )
    { $('#addfa').attr('disabled','disabled');} 
    if( facount >=4 )
    { $('#removefa').removeAttr("disabled");}
    if( facount <=3 )
    { $('#removefa').attr('disabled','disabled');} 
    if( facount <=8 )
    { $('#addfa').removeAttr("disabled");} 
}
```

And call this function after the submit of the form has run. You should also call this function from the click handlers (to minimise copied code)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    CheckButtons();
});
```

Comment: I tried this method.. but after that both buttons are not working.

Comment: Do you also re-populate the facount variable on form submit? If not then the value it is checking against will not be equivelant to the number of items you see.

Comment: I have also corrected my code for the `CheckButtons()` function to be correct based on your code.

Comment: Yes. I am using the php to update the facount value as mentioned in above code

Comment: I'm sorry I know virtually nothing about PHP. If you are using the above `CheckButtons()` function that I have now amended and you can check that the value of `countfa` is correct then the code should run successfully. Does the form submit cause a full postback?

Comment: Actually issue is with `$(document).ready() {`. On console it giving me error `missing ; before statement` I am checking this

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typo on my part. I've amended that code to be correct (`$(document).ready(function() {CheckButtons();});`)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is have a document ready check that looks to see if you have more than 2 input boxes viewable.  If you do, remove the disabled attribute.  The problem is that when you submit the form, your html is reset and the remove button has been set to disabled.